# AngularJS ng-repeat alias expression between multiple filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

According to [Angular ngRepeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), you can use the alias expression only at the end of `ngRepeat`:

> Please note that `as [variable name] is not an operator but rather a
>   part of ngRepeat micro-syntax so it can be used only at the end (and
>   not as operator, inside an expression).

In my `ng-repeat`, I need to filter out items based on property, and then use `limitTo` filter for pagination purposes.

How can I get number of filtered items before the second filter?

This doesnt ofcourse work:

```
item in c.items | filter: c.contextFilter as filteredItems | limitTo: c.pagination.pageSize : c.pagination.currentPage*c.pagination.pageSize
```

Is there any other way I can get the `filteredItems.length` value ?

Comment: it would be easy if you apply filters in the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, I fixed it assigning the result of the first part of the filter expression into a new variable. In your example:

````
    item in filteredItems = (c.items | filter: c.contextFilter) | limitTo: c.pagination.pageSize : c.pagination.currentPage*c.pagination.pageSize```
````

`<div>{{filteredItems.length}}</div>`

Full example with `controllerAs` syntax:

```
   item in $ctrl.filteredItems = ($ctrl.items | filter: $ctrl.customFilter | 
   orderBy: $ctrl.order) | limitTo: $ctrl.pagination.pageSize : 
   $ctrl.pagination.currentPage*$ctrl.pagination.pageSize`
```